# Why does SSH hang when using following nftables rules?

Tags: ssh, nftables

```
$ cat /etc/nftables.conf
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table ip firewall {
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
    iif "lo" accept
    iif != "lo" ip daddr 127.0.0.0/8 drop
    tcp dport 22 accept
    ct state established,related accept
  }

  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
  }

  chain output {
    type filter hook output priority filter; policy drop;
    iif "lo" accept
    udp dport { 53, 123 } accept
    tcp dport { 53, 80, 443 } accept
    ct state established,related accept
  }
}
```

Connection eventually works, but it takes much longer than anticipated.

Running `journalctl -f`, I see `systemd[1]: Failed to start User Manager for UID 1000` before connections is finally established.

If I run `nft flush ruleset`, connection works immediately.

Comment: Found the issue… typo in `chain output`. `iif "lo" accept` should be `oif "lo" accept`.

Comment: if you only accept ssh for localhost, meaning locally, ehy you dont just bind ssh to localhost?

Answer (score 0):

For incoming connections ALL external incoming packets match this rule:

```
iif != "lo" ip daddr 127.0.0.0/8 drop
```

as they come on interface which is not a local loopback and their destination address is definitely not in 127.0.0.0/8 network. I am surprised it goes through even after some timeout unless you also have IPv6 up and running.

For all locally initiated outgoing connections which are not DNS, NTP, HTTP and HTTPS - they hit the output chain drop policy. Again - they should not work at all unless you also have IPv6 up and running.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Found issue, see comments.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue… typo in `chain output`. `iif "lo" accept` should be `oif "lo" accept`.